# BroadCast Receiver java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estoy haciendo una aplicación Android para una capturadora de códigos de barra, básicamente lo que hace la aplicación es:

Desde un menú de navegación yo selecciono una bodega que me lleva a un  fragmento y en este fragmento tengo un spinner y dos text view, yo selecciono un producto del spinner, después ingreso los kilos manualmente y con la capturadora leo el código de barras, en el momento que lee el código envía los datos a la base de datos, pero en el momento que cambio de bodega y realizo el mismo procedimiento al momento de leer el código de barras se cae el sistema por que no rescata ningún valor.

Llevo ya como dos semanas tratando de resolver este problema y no se por que al cambiar de bodega y vuelvo al fragmento no rescata los valores

```
private BroadcastReceiver mSamDataReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        kilos = edt1.getText().toString().trim();
        if (intent.getAction().equals(SCN_CUST_ACTION_SCODE)) {
            codigo_barras = intent.getStringExtra(SCN_CUST_EX_SCODE);
            edt2.setText(codigo_barras);

            System.out.println(kilos+ " " + codigo_barras+" "+ nombre);

            if (edt2 !=null){

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),R.string.msjeEnvio,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }){

                    @Override
                    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put(CATEGORIA,nombre);
                        params.put(CODIGO,codigo_barras);
                        params.put(KILOS,kilos);
                        return params;
                    }

                    };
Req.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

Mensaje desplegado en LogCat:

```
10-26 01:52:48.961 5742-5742/cl.parmex.lfigueroa.inventario E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                              at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
                                                                              at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
                                                                              at cl.parmex.lfigueroa.inventario.SpinFragment$2$2.onErrorResponse(SpinFragment.java:244)
                                                                              at com.android.volley.Request.deliverError(Request.java:598)
                                                                              at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:101)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: es importante agregues el mensaje desplegado en el LogCat.

Comment: Leslie, para resolver un problema que surge en una aplicación Android de forma rápida, debes revisar en el [LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html), de otra forma estarías a ciegas tratando de encontrar el problema, incluso el problema podría no estar provocado en el código que agregas en tu pregunta.

Comment: @Elenasys el mensaje del Logcat esta mas abajo del código

Comment: Gracias @Leslie! , cual es la línea 92 de tu código, veo es uno de los Toast.

Comment: @Elenasys el error deberia ser en el Toast que sale a continuacion     new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   Yo creo que es por que las variables donde se guardan los datos vienen vacias

Comment: Agregué una respuesta Leslie Karen =)

Answer (score 2):

El error de acuerdo a tu `LogCat` se genera en un Toast, y es aquí:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Debes usar el método [getMessage()](http://file://users/afzal/Dev/Android/android-sdk-macosx/docs/reference/java/lang/Throwable.html?is-external=true#getMessage()) para obtener el mensaje del error desplegado por volley, además puedes validar si `error` tiene valor null:

```
if(error != null){
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Respuesta Volley incorrecta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}
```

Comment: A esta respuesta le agregaria un else mostrando un error generico, Volley puede retornar el error en null y nunca te enterarias. Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Respuesta Volley incorrecta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Gracias Agustín!